# Overlap text between cells in table

Tags: microsoft-word, text-formatting

So I'm trying to create a layout for my thesis, which looks something like this:

```
[1] source | Chapter 1
[2] source | Lorem Ipsum
           | ullamcorper euismod, nunc metus euismod elit [1]
           | ctetur est vel, pellentesque ipsum. Praesent sed iaculis: [2]
           |   1. Option
           |   2. Option
           |   3. Option
           |   4. Option
```

Using a table this is done easily, But for numbered lists, I'd like to show the numbers more to the left, so it looks like this:

```
[1] source | Chapter 1
[2] source | Lorem Ipsum
           | ullamcorper euismod, nunc metus euismod elit [1]
           | ctetur est vel, pellentesque ipsum. Praesent sed iaculis: [2]
         1.| Option
         2.| Option
         3.| Option
         4.| Option
```

I've been trying to find a way to overlap the cells, by moving the rulers around, and changing settings. Allow Overlap in the Table settings did nothing.

Also the left column, is only used for showing the sources. So it does not always have a text. That is why overlapping would not matter for me. I just can't find the option to actually make it overlap.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you want there to be an actual vertical line between the two areas of your document, or is the line of pipes (|) in your examples just for illustration purposes?

Comment: There is no visible line, it's just for the illustration.

Comment: And should all the sources for a given chapter be listed on its first page, as shown, or should each page list the sources for the references that appear on that page?

Comment: Yeah it's limited to the sources used on that page. Preferably besides the paragraph that refers to it. I actually used textboxes first to get what I want, but that screwed up the IEEE citations. These are two screenshots of the textbox solution: https://gyazo.com/62d2133c6fa4bbf6e8609f25fb62473b https://gyazo.com/86deb093ab6e6c36a36579d350c8da3a

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn't use tables at all. Instead, I'd do something like this:

- Set a wide left page margin for the document.
- For the numbered lists, adjust the position of the list numbering so that if, for example, the hanging indent for the list paragraphs is 18 pt, the left indent of those paragraphs is set to -18 pt (i.e., the inverse of the hanging indent value). This will stick the numbering in the wide left margin and align the list text itself with the other document content.
- For the citations, create a new paragraph style just for them (or modify an existing style that you won't use for anything else), and click **Frame** on the **Format** menu so that all text in that paragraph style is stuck into a frame. Format the frame so that it's in the wide left margin, and vertically aligned 0 points (or as needed) relative to the paragraph that it belongs with. Add a top border to the paragraph style.
- To actually insert the citations, type each into a separate paragraph immediately *before* the paragraph that it belongs with, and then apply my new/modified citation style. The anchor icon should appear next to the following paragraph. If there's more than one citation for a given paragraph, just type them all before in separate paragraphs; they'll be combined into a single frame when you apply the style to them.

[image: Layout]

Comment: I'm going to try this next thing in the morning! I'll keep you updated, thanks!